# How to optimize react re-renders caused by state changes?

Tags: reactjs, optimization, redux, apollo-client

I have a tree-like structure represented on my UI. Let's imagine them like this:

[image]

There are buttons on these components and the user can dynamically add more B components inside A and C components inside each B. The underlying data structure looks very similar, it's in denormalized format something like this:

```json
{
  "compA": {
    "Aproperty1": "something",
    "Aproperty2": 5,
    "Bcomponents": [
      {
        "Bproperty": 13,
        "Ccomponents": []
      }
      ...
    ]
  }
}
```

Each component manipulate its own part in this structure identifying the right part with unique IDs.

The data has been stored in a redux store previously, nowadays I'm experimenting with GraphQL and Apollo client and I'm using Reactive variables but I think it's the same problem. Whenever I'm moving a slider in a C component it updates the reactive variable(or redux store) and since A Component and all the B Components are using the same variable the whole tree re-renders. Since we are talking about a slider it causes a lot of updates and it actually makes it laggy. I used debounce for the slider so it emits most of the updates but that's not the root cause and I'm feeling it's not the right fix.

At the end of the day I need the whole data available in Component A becuase that's the one which can submit it to the backend.

I could probably make it a little bit better by normalizing the data and denormalize it on submit since it would be faster to modify it but the re-render problem is still there and I guess that eats up much more resource.

What is the right way to approach this problem and avoid the re-render of the whole tree when I'm adjusting a slider in a C component?

Comment: If you pass data upwards with redux, it re-renders the respective parents, but if you pass it downwards, only the child elements will be re-rendered. I'd suggest passing downwards the submit function (which submits the data to the server) so the child doesn't need to pass data at all

Comment: You can have different Component and call then and each of them component can have different useEffect ans pass props as per requirment

Comment: @kmp Yes, it would be nice to pass the function downwards but then which is going to call it? I think the only logical place of the submit function is in Component A. The data needs to be submitted in a single piece so either I don't understand your point or it's not possible for children to don't pass any data.

Comment: My point is to use context instead of redux, because as I understand your problem, you want to submit the data in 1 piece with minimal rendering. Your application would have access to a submit function and all the neccessary data in the context which then can be consumed by the children, so it would be the only rendering process, minimalizing usage of resources

Comment: https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html

Comment: Redux should only be used to pass data on the same level imo (I've never used it for this particular reason)

Comment: Ahh, I understand, thank you for the clarification. And now it seems a good approach. I'd accept it as a good answer if you take the time to convert it to an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry for the clumsy code block..I'm tired, but I hope it's clear. Let me know.

Also use the [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html#reactcreatecontext) (obviously) if you need to tweak it in any way. This is only a basic approach, more like structural then practical.

```
// Context declaration
const MyContext = React.createContext({
  submitFn: () => Promise<void>, // -> this will be sent to the server
  changeDataFn: (data: any) => any, // -> this is required to change the data
  data: any // -> this is the data
});

// Don't be confused, it's not quite TypeScript
// needed types for clarity

...

// Wrap ComponentA with your context
<MyContext.Provider value={/* define your functions bodies and default values */}>
  <ComponentA />
</MyContext.Provider>

...

// Component A
export function ComponentA(props) {
  // Use MyContext.Consumer wherever you want to consume data
  // or you can use `useContext` instead of `Consumer` if you prefer

  // You may add data here if you have any
  // eg. ctx.changeData("Hello World")
  return <MyContext.Consumer>
    {ctx => /* render Component A stuff */}
  </MyContext.Consumer>
}

...

// Component B
export function ComponentB(props) {
  // You may add data to the context in Component B
  // using the changeData function
  return <MyContext.Consumer>
    {ctx => /* render Component B stuff */}
  </MyContext.Consumer>
}

...

// Component C
export function ComponentC(props) {
  // Finally make your api call here,
  // it should re-render this component only
  // eg. ctx.submitFn().then(() => console.log("Yeeey it works!"))
  return <MyContext.Consumer>
    {ctx => /* render Component C stuff */}
  </MyContext.Consumer>
}

// you don't have to consume the context in each children
// it's there to wrap your component in the context,
// so it can access the stored data in it
```